# INSERT operation not working in SQLITE using Java

Tags: java, mysql, sql, sqlite

I have run into a problem with SQLITE and Java. I have looked through some of the answers here which suggested the programmers to use exceptions. Which I did use but my code is still giving me this one error

```
java.sql.SQLException: no such table: australia
```

and the records are not being updated on the created database:

```
Class.forName("org.sqlite.JDBC");
                Connection connect = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlite:playlist.sqlite");
                System.out.println("Playlist db opened");
                Statement saveStatement = connect.createStatement();
                saveStatement.executeUpdate(makeTable);

                try {
                    ResultSet getAllSameGenre = artStmt.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM tracklist WHERE genre = '" + storeGenre + "' ORDER BY RANDOM() LIMIT 10");

                    while(getAllSameGenre.next()){
                        int id = 1;
                        String title = getAllSameGenre.getString("title");
                        String artist = getAllSameGenre.getString("artist");
                        String genre = getAllSameGenre.getString("genre");
                        String album = getAllSameGenre.getString("album");

                        Statement finalRecord = connect.createStatement();
                        String storeTableName = playlistNameInsert.getText();
                        String record = "INSERT INTO " + storeTableName + " (id , title, artist , genre , album )" +  "VALUES ( '" +id+title+artist+genre+album+ " ' ); " ;
                        finalRecord.executeUpdate(record);

                        id ++;
                    }
                    saveStatement.close();
                    connect.close();
                }
                catch(Exception e){
                    System.out.println(e);
                }
```

Comment: You are inserting one value into five columns.  As is typical, if you printed out the SQL after variable substitution, the problem would be obvious.

Comment: I think it is the problem with your insert query.Please update insert statement like this "INSERT INTO TABLE_NAME(ID,TITLE,ARTIST,GENRE,ALBUM)
VALUES (4, 'TITLE', 'ARTIST', 'GENRE', 'ALBUM_NAME' );"

Answer (score 0):

The value of `playlistNameInsert.getText()` has the value of `Australia`, whereas you do not have a `table` with such a name. You need to make sure that you only `select from`, `insert into`, `delete from`, or `update` `table`s which exist in the `database` you are working with. Also, you need to separate values by comma, so this part seems fishy as well:

```
+id+title+artist+genre+album+
```

not to mention that if a value is textual, then you need to wrap apostrophes around it. It seems that you are not fluent with SQL syntax, so I think you should watch a few tutorials and then come back to this problem.